# Delete configurable products with associated products programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, delete

How can I delete a programmatically created configurable product with it's associate products?

Comment: I have tried retrieving the simple products from the configurable product and delete each simple product and then delete the configurable product.. it's a bit of a code, so thought there might be another way I can achieve this simpler

Comment: If you need help with the code you can post it here. If you're looking for a different way: Magento does not have a method like that out of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the configurable product:

```
$productId = 100;//change this to what you need
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$productIds = $conf->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
//delete the simple products
foreach ($productIds as $id) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->delete();
}
//delete the conf product 
$conf->delete();
```

I know this is no the fastest way to do it and it uses `load` in loops but if you don't need to delete hundred of products or you don't need to call this constanlly you should be OK

Comment: so it seems that this is the way to delete associated products with the configurable product... thanks